# Excel VBA - assign Sort order to variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that works perfectly:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("compleanni").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
                                                                       "I6:I23"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortTextAsNumbers
```

I'd like to change it like this:

```
myorder="xlAscending"
....
....
Order:=myorder
```

but it doesn't work: I get run-time error 13.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Get rid of the quotation marks in the assignment and it should work.

Comment: try `myorder = xlAscending`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xlAscending` is a predefined constant in VBA (Excel), its type is `long` (value is 1, but that's not important).

Dim your variable `myorder` as `Long` and assing the constant:

```
Dim myorder as Long
myorder = xlAscending ' (or xlDescending)
```